# Преобразовать строку в кортеж с числами

Tags: python, pandas, tuple

В результате парсинга и неудачного сохранения/открытия csv-файла у меня столбец Pandas, который называется "point", содержит строки `str` с координатами по типу `('55.2222', '77.9999')`. Каждый элемент -- это строка (и скобки тоже). Подскажите, как из этого сделать классический кортеж `(55.2222, 77.9999)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку каждый элемент целиком строка, то видимо проще всего так:

```
from ast import literal_eval

tuple(map(float, literal_eval("('55.2222', '77.9999')")))
```

Т.е. сначала превращаем строку в "настоящий" кортеж (но по-прежнему со строками внутри), а потом уже, как написал в ответе Danis, превращаем элементы кортежа из строк в `float`.

Для `Pandas` это будет выглядеть примерно так в итоге:

```
df['point'] = df.point.apply(lambda x: tuple(map(float, literal_eval(x))))
```

P.S. О том, что надо использовать в таких случаях именно `literal_eval`, а не просто `eval`, написано уже много ответов, я их не буду повторять. Кроме того, можно разобрать строку и "вручную", но раз есть для этого специальная функция - лучше воспользоваться ей, чтобы не учитывать нюансы, которые могут возникнуть.

Answer (score 1):

```
tuple_ = ('55.2222', '77.9999')

print(tuple(map(float, tuple_)))
```

с помощью `map` превращаем каждый элемент в `float`

а если у вас `tuple_` такой `"('55.2222', '77.9999')"` то так:

```
print(tuple(map(lambda x: float(x[2:-2]), tuple_[1:-1].split(", ")))
```

Comment: Я плюс поставил, но похоже в вопросе требуется не совсем это )